# Docx is not replacing texts that's extracted from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, docx

I'm creating a program to extract certain text and to change the name as well as the firm's to personalize the message. But when I pull out the names as well as the firm's names from the excel sheet, the printing function only prints out the unedited form.

I tried using a different library, OpenPyXl. I also tried not using a dictionary; but it always ended the same way.

```
firm = []
for x in range(len(list_of)):
    firm.append(list_of.iloc[x,1])

name = []

for x in range(len(list_of)):
    name.append(list_of.iloc[x,0])

for integer in range(len(firm)):

    dic = {'firstname':name[integer],'your_firm': firm[integer]}
    for p in form.paragraphs:
        inline = p.runs
        for i in range(len(inline)):
            text = inline[i].text
            if text in dic.keys():
                text=text.replace(text,dic[text])
                inline[i].text = text
        print(p.text)
```

I expect the print function to return something like, "Dear John from Microsoft".

Comment: Please provide a minimal and complete example of input and expected output.

Comment: I believe I did.

Comment: Do you mean the doc file?

Answer (score 0):

You're most probably a victim of words splitted across `w:t`.

### Explanation :

A typical `word/document.xml` looks like this :

```
<w:body>
  <w:p w:rsidR="001A6335" w:rsidRPr="0059122C" w:rsidRDefault="0059122C" w:rsidP="0059122C">
    <w:r>
      <w:t>Hello {n</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
    <w:r w:rsidR="008B4316">
      <w:t>am</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>e}</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
  </w:p>
  <w:sectPr w:rsidR="001A6335" w:rsidRPr="0059122C" w:rsidSect="001A6335">
    <w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId7"/>
    <w:footerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId8"/>
    <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
    <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1800" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1800" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
    <w:cols w:space="720"/>
    <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
  </w:sectPr>
</w:body>
```

The tags are `w:body` (for the whole document), and then the document is separated in multiple `w:p` (paragraphs). And a `w:sectPr`, which defines the headers/footers used for that document.

Inside a `w:p`, there are multiple `w:r` (runs). Every run defines its own style (color of the text, font-size, ...), and every run contains multiple `w:t` (text parts).

As you can see, a simple sentence like `Hello {name}` might be separated in multiple `w:t`, which makes templating quite difficult to implement.

In your example, most probably the replacement is done on "first_name", but probably this string is splitted across multiple `w:t`.

I would recommend you to use a tool that has been created for that purpose : https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template

I also maintain such a module myself but it however runs with Javascript (either in the browser or on a server), see https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater if you're still interested.